# Send email with Symfony2 without password

Tags: symfony, email

I'm trying to send mails with my application that is located in a server with all permissions to send mails without password for the account that I use. With the system comand "mail" this operation is sucessfull, but with symfony I get "Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "user@domain" using 2 possible authenticators". How can I solved this problem.

Comment: The problem was with transport, as I have the function in a Symfony Command and it's executed in console, the transport is mail and not smtp in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `null` as the value of the `password` configuration option? Check out the [complete reference of SwiftMailer options](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html)